# Adding ASP v1 support to IIS6

Tags: iis-6, asp-classic

I have IIS6 running Win2003 Server and (unfortunately) I need to get one terribly old code base running on it. It uses classic ASP v1 and it appears that this particular box has no support for it in IIS6. Hence my question - how do I add one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS6 has ASP Classic support out of the box.

To activate it, you your IIS6 management console, you need to go to Web Services Extensions and ensure that ASP is enabled in there.

Then, under your website, you will need to ensure that it has the ability to execute scripts. Go to the Home Directory tab and ensure that Scripts is ticked. I don't think you need to create an 'Application' (I think this is just for ASP .NET but I'm not 100% sure).

**Edit:** After reading Brian's comments these instructions may not be relevant to you. I inherited an old app once that used depreciated commands from older versions of ASP and I ended up having to write a wrapper to go around them. If they're no good let me know and I'll delete/demote this post.

Comment: It is classic ASP 3.0, though. Can he really mean ASP 1.0 from IIS 3 in the NT 4 Option Pack? One problem he may run into is COM objects that are no longer supported, like the CDONTS.NewMail COM object doesn't exist on Windows 2003 but there is a similar CDO.Message object. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Ooooohh, gotcha. I hated that CDONTS object, I inherited an app that used and and quite correct, it doesn't work on IIS6